# How does this code work to reverse bits in number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, reverse

```
unsigned reverse_bits(unsigned input)
{  
     //works on 32-bit machine  
     input = (input & 0x55555555) <<  1 | (input & 0xAAAAAAAA) >>  1;
     input = (input & 0x33333333) <<  2 | (input & 0xCCCCCCCC) >>  2;
     input = (input & 0x0F0F0F0F) <<  4 | (input & 0xF0F0F0F0) >>  4;
     input = (input & 0x00FF00FF) <<  8 | (input & 0xFF00FF00) >>  8;
     input = (input & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (input & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;

      return input;
}
```

how does this work?

Comment: Swap halves, swap quarters, swap eights...

Comment: Why don't you work it out with pencil and paper? Use an 8 bit number and only go up to 0x0F/0xF0.

Comment: He is facing problem thats why he has posted this on SE.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Suppose I have a hand of 8 cards:

```
7 8 9 10 J Q K A
```

How can we reverse them? One way is to swap adjacent pairs:

```
8 7 10 9 Q J A K
```

Then, swap adjacent groups of 2: exchange 8 7 and 10 9, etc:

```
10 9 8 7 A K Q J
```

Finally, exchange groups of four, which is half the size of 8:

```
A K Q J 10 9 8 7
```

Done.

You can do this in different orders. Why? Because the exchanges are *stable* with respect to each other. When we exchange the upper half of the cards with the lower half, for instance, the pairs stay in the same order. Or when we exchange pairs, the halves stay in the same order.

This is what the code is doing with the bit operations. For instance to swap pairs we can use the mask 01010101 to pick out the even bits, and 10101010 to pick out the odd bits, using the bitwise AND operation:

```
  ABCDEFGH     ABCDEFGH
& 01010101   & 10101010
----------   ----------
= 0B0D0F0H     A0C0E0G0
```

Remember, the rule for and is that given some bit value X,  X & 1 = X   and X & 0 = 0. The 1 bits in the mask preserve the value, and the 0 bits in the mask produce 0. This is called masking because it looks exactly like a mask used in spray-painting, etc. The 1 bits "cover" the places you don't want to "paint" with zero.

Next, the left result is shifted left one bit, and the right result shifted right. This brings about the swap:

```
  B0D0F0H0     0A0C0E0G
```

Finaly, the two are combined with logical OR. The rule for OR is that X or 0 is X. The two parts each have 0 where the other has nonzero, and so the bits simply merge:

```
  B0D0F0H0
| 0A0C0E0G
----------
= BADCFEHG
```

And now the pairs are swapped.

Comment: Wow excellent answer! I didn't understand how it even worked to begin with, but now I do thanks to your answer!

Answer (score 9):

The code first swaps single adjacent bits, then adjacent pairs of bits, and so on, doubling the size of the swap each time until chunks half the size of the integer are swapped at the end.  The swapping is done by masking off the bits to be moved with AND, shifting them and then OR'ing the results together.

The animation below is helpful for visualizing what's going on, remembering that while the swap sizes increase sequentially, all the swaps at each size occur in parallel.

[image: swapping]

Answer (score 8):

It can be understood by induction.

Start with the base case, a two bit number

```
input = (input & 0x1) <<  1 | (input & 0x2) >>  1;
```

Now progress to a four bit number

```
input = (input & 0x5) <<  1 | (input & 0xA) >>  1; // swap bits
input = (input & 0x3) <<  2 | (input & 0xc) >>  2; // swap bit pairs
```

Progress to an 8 bit number

```
input = (input & 0x55) <<  1 | (input & 0xAA) >>  1; // swap bits
input = (input & 0x33) <<  2 | (input & 0xCC) >>  2; // swap bit pairs
input = (input & 0x0F) <<  4 | (input & 0xF0) >>  4; // swap bit nibbles
```

and so on.

Comment: Great explanation !! The word for the day is `induction`, which made the rest of it so much simple to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Let `b[0], b[1], b[2], ..., b[31]` are bits of `input` beginning from the least significant bit. Then `b[1], b[0], b[3], b[2], ..., b[31], b[30]` will be bits of

```
input = (input & 0x55555555) <<  1 | (input & 0xAAAAAAAA) >>  1;
```

Basically, it swaps neighboring bits of `input`. Similar, other 4 lines swaps neighboring pairs, groups of 4, groups of 8, and finally groups of 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned reverse_bits(unsigned input)
{  
     //works on 32-bit machine  
     input = (input & 0x55555555) <<  1 | (input & 0xAAAAAAAA) >>  1;
     input = (input & 0x33333333) <<  2 | (input & 0xCCCCCCCC) >>  2;
     input = (input & 0x0F0F0F0F) <<  4 | (input & 0xF0F0F0F0) >>  4;
     input = (input & 0x00FF00FF) <<  8 | (input & 0xFF00FF00) >>  8;
     input = (input & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (input & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
     printf("\nvalue = %x",input);
     return input;
}

int _tmain()
{
    // TODO: Please replace the sample code below with your own.

    int value;
    signed int res,bit;
    signed int stPos, len;
    value = 0x12345678;

    reverse_bits(value);
    printf("\nvalue = %x",value);
    char buffer [33];
    itoa (value,buffer,2);
    printf ("\nbinary: %s\n",buffer);

    return 0;
}
```